# How to change direction in snake game

Tags: c++, string

I have this code, part of a snake game
when you hit a key, it will have to go down, but vertically, at start my snake goes horizontally, when I hit a key it will go down,but not vertically, it goes down horizontally, and this is not true, how can I fix this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void gotoxy(int eex, int eey)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = eex;
    coord.Y = eey;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

int main()
{

    int x=0,y=10,lx=0,ly=0;
    for(int i=10;;i++)
    {
        gotoxy(i,y);
        cout<<"***";
        Sleep(100);
        lx=i;
        ly=y;
        gotoxy(lx,ly);
        cout<<"   ";
        if(kbhit())
        {
            for(int j=ly;;j++)
            {
                gotoxy(lx,j);
                cout<<"***";
                Sleep(100);
                ly=j;
                gotoxy(lx,ly);
                cout<<"   ";
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is unreadable. Please format it (indent each line) for readability.

Comment: If you do the same thing on Stack Overflow then you will eventually get the same response. The question will be closed and deleted, no matter how many times you post it.

Comment: my post got 23 view but no answers

Comment: Your post got deleted. Did you delete it?

Comment: @Dialecticus i just change my Subject and make a clarification :) if u couldnt help me don't bother please

Comment: @Dialecticus i deleted because it was some vague

Comment: no,this is not a Duplicate,i have to see some code  to fix this problem

Comment: @Ahmadreza Don't get rude please. _'how can I fix this problem?'_ Use a debugger and step through your code, instead of expecting someone here to do this for you. That simple, no more implications, that's why the down and close votes are applied to your question.

Comment: I still don't get how can something go down horizontally, that is - once we exclude dirty jokes

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if i know how can i fix this problem i never asked this question,if you know plz help me :(

Comment: @Leeor Simulate Snake Game Movement,or run my code,you will find out

Comment: @Ahmadreza Again: To check what's going on, use a debugger, put breakpoints of interest, and step through ...

Comment: @Leeor *** this is snake,it goes *** when i push a key i excpect goes down *

Comment: @Ahmadreza _'... run my code,you will find out ...'_ [Your code doesn't run :(](http://ideone.com/BN8GwM) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is "how to fix this code", not "give me the right code". I will not give you the right code. I will answer the original question. The answer to that question is this:

The problem is that you do `cout << "***"`. This will alwys draw three asterisks horizontally. That command will never do anything else. To draw items vertically, or which ever shape the snake may make, you have to draw each asterisk separatelly, on its own coordinate.

Instead of having only one coordinate (variables `x` and `y`) you have to have the coordinates of every part of the snake. Use `std::queue<COORD>` to remember the coordinate of every part of the snake. To make the snake move draw space (" ") on the last item in the queue and remove the last item from the back of the queue (`pop_back`), and add new item in the front of the queue (`push_front`) and draw asterisk there ("*").

When you want to make the snake bigger don't remove items from the queue, but just add new.

Comment: Give me the right Code plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz :((((((

Comment: @Ahmadreza there is code on the internet. Try googling for c++ snake.

Comment: @Ahmadreza _'Give me the right Code plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz :(((((('_ As mentioned please don't ask here to debug and fix your code. If you encounter some particular point in your code, where you don't understand the behavior, highlight this in your questiion and describe the problem!