# How to use queue to move my snake with c++

Tags: c++, string

i have some problem in changing Direction of my snake,how to change this code,because i want Instead of having only one coordinate (variables x and y) i have to have the coordinates of every part of the snake. Using std::queue to remember the coordinate of every part of the snake. To make the snake move draw space (" ") on the last item in the queue and remove the last item from the back of the queue (pop_back), and add new item in the front of the queue (push_front) and draw asterisk there ("*").
help me to implement this 
this is my code but it works wrong,because with this code my snake didn't change the direction and instead goes down vertically it goes down horizontally

My Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void gotoxy(int eex, int eey)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = eex;
    coord.Y = eey;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

int main()
{

    int x=0,y=10,lx=0,ly=0;
    for(int i=10;;i++)
    {
        gotoxy(i,y);
        cout<<"***";
        Sleep(100);
        lx=i;
        ly=y;
        gotoxy(lx,ly);
        cout<<"   ";
        if(kbhit())
        {
            for(int j=ly;;j++)
            {
                gotoxy(lx,j);
                cout<<"***";
                Sleep(100);
                ly=j;
                gotoxy(lx,ly);
                cout<<"   ";
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i dont't know how change my coorinate

Comment: not clear about your implemented idea. please write your approach in a step wise manner.

Comment: @SantoshSahu look,i want to implement snake changing direction,if u run my code you will see instead of changing direction and goes down vertically it goes down horizontally because of cout<<"***"; i dont know how to change this code and save every coordinate to simulating this move in correct way

Comment: Stack Overflow has a culture of not giving code to beginners, because we think beginners must learn to code, so that they could be useful to the rest of the community. I'm interested to see if someone would actually give you the code in spite of this culture. There are plenty of people, but very few that have both the time and the right attitude to just give you the code.

Comment: @Dialecticus i have a code i think you have to see this,and you will never call me beginner :)

Comment: Did you download it from internet maybe? What is your goal here anyway? Do you want to learn to code, or do you want to finish a homework?

Comment: :) i didn't download it from internet,you can search the internet for that,i want to learn code,but im a shell programmer and this isn't my home work,it just for fun ,but my mind didn't give me an idea for this,so i decided to ask this here

Comment: Well, learning can't be fun all the time. Sometimes you have to push harder. I told you there are code examples on the internet, for instance [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/606629-console-snake-game-in-c/) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/3U75fSEw/). You asked for code, so there it is. The code maybe does not work, but you will learn a lot just by studying it.

Comment: Maybe you will learn so much that you will be able to fix errors in the code and make it work. That would be awesome!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change direction in snake game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822480/how-to-change-direction-in-snake-game)